# Pandas JSON Table

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use the first `type` object (always starts with "document_") from this json as a row and all others as a column

```json
[
  [
    {
      "type": "document_type_bank_statement"
    },
    {
      "type": "sender_iban"
    },
    {
      "type": "sender_vat_id"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "type": "document_type_bank_statement"
    },
    {
      "type": "sender_iban"
    },
    {
      "type": "sender_vat_id"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "type": "document_type_invoice"
    },
    {
      "type": "sender_zip"
    }
  ]
]
```

Example:

|  | sender_iban | sender_vat_id | sender_zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| document_type_bank_statement | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| document_type_invoice | 0 | 0 | 1 |

This will give me the first object:

```py
for type in pagewise_data:
    print(type[0]['type'])
```

So all the others:

```py
for type in pagewise_data:
    for i in type:
        if not i['type'].startswith('document'):
            print(i['type'])
```

This is how i get all `types`

```py
for type in pagewise_data:
    for i in type:
        print(i['type'])
```

My question now is, how do i get this to work like in my given example table with pandas? so that you can also count the existing `types` that occur in an array block?

Comment: How should that be possible?  `document_type_invoice` has far fewer columns then `document_type_bank_statement` ?

Comment: i have updated the json and table example with exact data as i imagine it, if no field occurs then 0 should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by loading our data using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
>>> df                                            0  ...                          2
0  {'type': 'document_type_bank_statement'}  ...  {'type': 'sender_vat_id'}
1  {'type': 'document_type_bank_statement'}  ...  {'type': 'sender_vat_id'}
2         {'type': 'document_type_invoice'}  ...                       None
```

Then, we can `.melt` our dataframe to create pairs of values (first value as future ID and the second value that will be counted in a column at the end). We'll drop NaN values too:

```
>>> df = df.melt(id_vars=[0]).drop("variable", axis=1)
>>> df = df.dropna()
>>> df
                                          0                      value
0  {'type': 'document_type_bank_statement'}    {'type': 'sender_iban'}
1  {'type': 'document_type_bank_statement'}    {'type': 'sender_iban'}
2         {'type': 'document_type_invoice'}     {'type': 'sender_zip'}
3  {'type': 'document_type_bank_statement'}  {'type': 'sender_vat_id'}
4  {'type': 'document_type_bank_statement'}  {'type': 'sender_vat_id'}
```

Since each value is a `dict` with a `"type"` key, we'll use `.applymap` to take the corresponding value of that key for each cell in our dataframe:

```
>>> df = df.applymap(lambda d: d["type"])
>>> df
                              0          value
0  document_type_bank_statement    sender_iban
1  document_type_bank_statement    sender_iban
2         document_type_invoice     sender_zip
3  document_type_bank_statement  sender_vat_id
4  document_type_bank_statement  sender_vat_id
```

Finally, let's use `pd.pivot_table` to format our data and count the frequency of each term. Use the `fill_value` argument to fill the output with zeros. Also, we can format our index:

```
>>> df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=[0], columns=["value"], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
>>> df.index = df.index.map(lambda _id: _id[9:])
>>> df
value                sender_iban  sender_vat_id  sender_zip
0                                                          
type_bank_statement            2              2           0
type_invoice                   0              0           1
```

---

Resulting code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.melt(id_vars=[0]).drop("variable", axis=1)
df = df.dropna()
df = df.applymap(lambda d: d["type"])
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=[0], columns=["value"], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
df.index = df.index.map(lambda _id: _id[9:])
```

Comment: wow, works perfect! but i would like to have nothing instead of "value" in the top left, how do i do that? i get an error as soon as i remove this

Comment: It's just the name of the column index, you can remove it using `df.columns.name = None`

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

def extract_type(value):
    if value is not None:
        return value["type"]
    return value


def count_values(df):
    counter = Counter(
        list(chain.from_iterable([list(row[1]) for row in df.iterrows()]))
    )
    del counter[None]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counter.items()).set_index(0).T


original_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(test_data)
extracted_types = original_data.applymap(extract_type).set_index(0)
counted_values = extracted_types.groupby(0).apply(count_values).fillna(0).droplevel(1)
```

If test_data is data you provided counted_values should contain:

| 0 | sender_iban | sender_vat_id | sender_zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| document_type_bank_statement | 2.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 |
| document_type_invoice | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |